# There was no endpoint listening

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I'm trying to host my own wcf and staying out of the app.config file. My wcf service ispart of my wpf project. the host code is.

```
host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), new Uri("http://" + System.Net.Dns.GetHostName() + ":8733/DatabaseTransferWcfServiceLibaryMethod/Service1/"));
ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
if (smb == null)
{
    smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
}

BasicHttpBinding q = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
q.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 1, 0);
q.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 1, 0);
q.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 1, 0);
q.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 1, 0);
q.AllowCookies = false;
q.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
q.MaxBufferSize = 2147483646;
q.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483646;
q.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483646;
q.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483646;
q.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483646;
q.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2147483646;
q.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483646;
q.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483646;
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), q, "");
smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Default;
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), q, "http://" + System.Net.Dns.GetHostName() + ":8733/DatabaseTransferWcfServiceLibaryMethod/Service1/");
host.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());


host.Open();
```

My client code where I get the error is.

```
var ep = "http://" + System.Net.Dns.GetHostName() + ":8733/DatabaseTransferWcfServiceLibaryMethod/Service1/";
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;
binding.SendTimeout = new System.TimeSpan(0, 1, 30);

ChannelFactory<IService1> wcfFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(binding, new EndpointAddress(ep));

IService1 wcf = wcfFactory.CreateChannel();
System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 200;
wcf.generateId(System.Environment.MachineName);
```

I have turned my firewall off so it isn't that causing the error.

Any ideas as where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Did you run the client and server on the same machine? If not you need to change `System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()` to the server's address (in your client code).

Comment: Yeah it is the same machine

Comment: First of all I have found some errors in your code after execution: 1. System.InvalidOperationException: A ServiceDiscoveryBehavior is required to support the DiscoveryEndpoint. 2. System.InvalidOperationException: This service has multiple endpoints listening at 'http://localhost:8733/DatabaseTransferWcfServiceLibaryMethod/Service1/' which share the same initiating action 'http://tempuri.org/IService1/GenerateId'

Comment: In your app.config you have left in the defined endpoints in there that's why you are getting errors like that.

Comment: I have no idea why but since starting my computer up again it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the comments. When I made these two changes everything works fine

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), new Uri("http://" + System.Net.Dns.GetHostName() + ":8733/DatabaseTransferWcfServiceLibaryMethod/Service1/"));
    ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
    if (smb == null)
    {
        smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
    }

    BasicHttpBinding q = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
    q.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 1, 0);
    q.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 1, 0);
    q.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 1, 0);
    q.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 1, 0);
    q.AllowCookies = false;
    q.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
    q.MaxBufferSize = 2147483646;
    q.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483646;
    q.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483646;
    q.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483646;
    q.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483646;
    q.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2147483646;
    q.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483646;
    q.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483646;
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), q, "");
    smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
    smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Default;

    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
    // ADD ServiceDiscoveryBehavior
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior());

    // COMMENT THIS LINE
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), q, "http://" + System.Net.Dns.GetHostName() + ":8733/DatabaseTransferWcfServiceLibaryMethod/Service1/");
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());


    host.Open();

    var ep = "http://" + System.Net.Dns.GetHostName() + ":8733/DatabaseTransferWcfServiceLibaryMethod/Service1/";
    var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;
    binding.SendTimeout = new System.TimeSpan(0, 1, 30);

    ChannelFactory<IService1> wcfFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(binding, new EndpointAddress(ep));

    IService1 wcf = wcfFactory.CreateChannel();
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 200;
    Console.WriteLine(wcf.GenerateId(System.Environment.MachineName));
}
```